# Find all $x\in\mathbb{C^n}$ such that $||Ax||_2=1$ and $||x||_2=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, svd, singular-values

Given $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, find all $x\in\mathbb{C^n}$ such that $||Ax||_2=1$ and $||x||_2=1$.

Lets do SVD: $A=U\Sigma V^*$, where $\Sigma=\mathrm{diag}\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\}$.

We do change of a coordinates $x=Vy,$ then we need to find $y\in\mathbb{C^n}$ such that $||\Sigma y||_2=1$ and $||y||_2=1$.

Comment: Note that $\|\Sigma y \|^2 = 1$ is the same as $\sigma_1^2 y_1^2 + \cdots + \sigma_n^2 y_n^2 = 1$. This is the equation of an ellipsoid in $n$ dimensions.

Comment: so I need to find points where this ellipsoid touches a sphere given by $||y||_2=1$?

Comment: You could also use regular optimization methods and use $ {\left\| x \right\|}_{2}^{2} \leq 1 $ to have a convex function. Then find the $ \lambda $ for equality.

Comment: @Royi since I am searching for all $x$ that satisfy certain constraints, I am not sure how this problem can be formulated as optimization problem.

Comment: What do you mean by all $x$? It’s easy to describe (intersection of an ellipsis and a sphere). It has nontrivial solutions whenever the singular values have min at most one and max at least one. A rational parametrization (impossible?) is very difficult, but it’s not too hard to project into the axis of the lowest singular value which will give you an ellipsoid that you can inverse project onto 2 pieces on the sphere.

Comment: @Eric Can you please answer or comment more on what do you mean by "project into the axis of the lowest singular value which will give you an ellipsoid that you can inverse project onto 2 pieces on the sphere"? I never seen such method, not sure what to do

Comment: Subtract the ellipsoid formula from the sphere one so that the $x_1^2$ term cancels out. You’ll get that $x_2$,...,$x_n$ form an ellipse. You can then use these to select the 0,1, or 2 values of $x_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the system

$\left\{ \begin{matrix} \sigma_1^2|y_1|^2+\sigma_2^2|y_2|^2+\ldots+\sigma_n^2|y_n|^2=1 \\ |y_1|^2+|y_2|^2+\ldots+|y_n|^2=1 \end{matrix}\right.$

Let $\sigma_i=\max\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\}$ and $\sigma_j=\min\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\}$.

We are assuming that $\sigma_i^2>1>\sigma_j^2\geq0$.

We can rewrite this system as

$\left\{ \begin{matrix} \sigma_i^2|y_i|^2+\sigma_j^2|y_j|^2=1-\sum_{l\neq i,j}\sigma_l^2|y_l|^2\\ |y_i|^2+|y_j|^2=1-\sum_{l\neq i,j}|y_l|^2 \end{matrix}\right.$

By Cramer's rule, we obtain

$|y_j|^2=\det\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_i^2 & 1-\sum_{l\neq i,j}\sigma_l^2 |y_l|^2\\ 1 & 1-\sum_{l\neq i,j}|y_l|^2\end{pmatrix}/\det\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_i^2 & 
\sigma_j^2\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and  $|y_i|^2=\det\begin{pmatrix}1-\sum_{l\neq i,j}\sigma_l|y_l|^2 & \sigma_j^2\\ 1-\sum_{l\neq i,j}|y_l|^2 & 1\end{pmatrix}/\det\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_i^2 & \sigma_j^2\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Notice that

1. $\det\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_i^2 & \sigma_j^2\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}=\sigma_i^2-\sigma_j^2>0$
2. $\det\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_i^2 & 1-\sum_{l\neq i,j}\sigma_l^2|y_l|^2\\ 1 & 1-\sum_{l\neq i,j}x_l^2\end{pmatrix}=\sigma_i^2-1+\sum_{l\neq i,j}(\sigma_l^2-\sigma_i^2)|y_l|^2$.

Since $\sigma_l^2-\sigma_i^2\leq 0$ e $0<\sigma_i^2-1$, we can find a solution when $\sum_{l\neq i,j}(\sigma_i^2-\sigma_l^2)x_l^2\leq \sigma_i^2-1.$

3. $\det\begin{pmatrix}1-\sum_{l\neq i,j}\sigma_l^2|y_l|^2 & \sigma_j^2\\ 1-\sum_{l\neq i,j}|y_l|^2 & 1\end{pmatrix}=1-\sigma_j^2+\sum_{l\neq i,j}(\sigma_j^2-\sigma_l^2)|y_l|^2$.

Since $\sigma_j^2-\sigma_l^2\leq 0$ e $0<1-\sigma_j^2$, we can find a solution when $\sum_{l\neq i,j}(\sigma_l^2-\sigma_j^2)|y_l|^2\leq 1-\sigma_j^2.$